# transfer files between local machine and remote server

Tags: python

I want to make access from remote ubuntu server to local machine because I have multiple files in this machine and I want to transfer it periodically (every minute) to server how can I do that using python

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Did you tried `cron` job with `scp`? That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your local machine OS and network setup, I would recommend the following:

## File transfers

Based on the file size, if its a small copy, I would use `scp` (secure copy). This is because of the simplicity of the command.

In most use cases however I would use `rsync` because of its great capabilities, most importantly the ability to handle failed partial transfers. It works by analysing the differences between the source and destination. It has pretty much every preference under the sun available (overwriting, deltas, etc.)

Note that when using these commands in an automation script over a longer period of time, you'll probably want to set up a static IP or DDNS for your remote machine.

## Python

To run shell commands in a Python script, use `pexpect`. Its built around the original C based `expect` and it's fantastic. I used it the other day to transfer a folder from a dev computer to a number of different Raspberry Pis remotely at the same time. Check out the documentation here: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

## Automation

As for automation, it really depends on how you want it set up. If you want the python script responsible for transferring data to be called when you want to transfer data you could look into `crontab`. It's very well known by admins so easy to Google.

Alternatively, if this is part of a Python app you could have the app running in the background and sleeping (`time.sleep()` or a time elapsed function to check) between transfers. If you needed to do other things in the same Python app then you could stick the whole transfer and sleep part into a thread (also easily implemented in Python).

*I hope this helps, let me know if you want details elaborated.*

Comment: thank you for your reply replay but I want to run python script on server to bring files that generate automatically from local machine

Comment: @user8424107 shouldn't be a problem, when you use `scp` or `rsync` you can specify source&destination. The source can be an external filesystem e.g. `rsync -a --progress pi@machine.local:/home/pi /Users/me/Desktop/`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily transfer files between local and remote or between two remote servers. If both servers are Linux-based and require to transfer multiple files and folder using single command, however, you need to follow up below steps:

- User from one remote server should have access to another remote server to corresponding directory you want to transfer the file.
- You might need to create a policy or group and assign to server list to that group
  which you want to access and assign the user to that group so 2 different remote
  server can talk to each other.
- Run the following scp command:-

  ```
    scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 
    username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
  ```